# Get the UITextfield textFieldDidEndEditing callback in a custom UIPicker class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipicker

According to my requirement I need a UIPicker in multiple sections of my app with the same list. So I'm creating a custom class of UIPicker and so far i didn't receive any problem but one thing i would like improve is currently I'm setting the value from the textfield delegate method lets take a example :-

**MembershipPickerView.h**

```
@interface MembershipPickerview : UIPickerView <UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray <Membership *> *membershipData;
@end
```

**MembershipPickerView.m**

```
@implementation MembershipPickerview{
    NSArray <Membership *> *membershipData;
}

-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.dataSource  = self;
        self.delegate = self;
        [self updateDataSource];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)updateDataSource{
    Membership *m1 = [Membership new];
    m1.mName = @"M1";
    m1.mId = @"1";

    Membership *m2 = [Membership new];
    m1.mName = @"M2";
    m1.mId = @"2";
    membershipData = @[m1,m2];

    [self reloadAllComponents];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(nonnull UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(nonnull UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return membershipData.count;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return membershipData[row].mName;
}
@end
```

Have a view controller lets say `vc1` that have a UITextfield in it named `textField1`

In my "vc1.m"

```
@implementation vc1 {
    UITextField *textField1;
    MembershipPickerview *picker;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    picker = [MembershipPickerview new];
    textField1.inputView = picker;
    textField1.delegate = self;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSInteger index = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",picker.membershipData[index].mName)
}
@end
```

**My Questions**

1. Can i achieve the functionality that I'm doing in the textFieldDidEndEditing within the class and without setting the delegate of textfield to picker? If yes, How?
2. Is it possible to get an event (textfield had resigned) in the Picker class without writing extra code in the other view controllers

Comment: Just put the delegates in this class and set the delegate of this the textfield to this class.

Comment: But i also need to use that delegate to other classes too.

Comment: If the picker is accessible from that class, then just write a method in the picker and call that method in `didEndEditing`?

Comment: textFieldDidEndEditing is doing pretty much of the work, I'm looking forward to get an event when the picker is closed so i can update the value at the other end with a block. @RakeshaShastri

Comment: You should create a custom UITextField class and in init of the textfield class add a pickerview as inputview. Create a instance of the custom textfield in all view controllers

Comment: That is probably the best solution, Totally agreed. However i was thinking isn't it possible to get an event when the UIPicker is closed?

Comment: what do you mean - get an event when the UIPicker is closed

Comment: Exactly, like when we switch to another textfield.

Comment: I've used this approach in swift. So there will be no problem in using multiple textfields

Comment: I totally got your using a different textfield point and i know it'll surely work but i was concerned about getting the event from the starting of my question. @RajeshKumarR

Comment: You can try subscribing to [UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfieldtextdidendeditingnotification?language=objc)